# android Sharedpreferences and Sqlite saved data

Tags: android, database, sqlite, save, sharedpreferences

I am working on an app that involves a lot of sqlite database functions and sharedpreferences...

I would like to ask whether the sharedpreferences and sqlite data will be kept if the user updates the app through the Google Play?

Comment: almost a duplicate, except the Sqlite part of the question is not in the duplicate. By closing based on the sharedpreferences, we lose a datapoint regarding sqlite info. and the next person worried about sqlite data being lost on an update gets to write another question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All `SharedPreferences` and databases are kept upon update. Your database will be upgraded if you change the database version on your SQLite helper class.

Comment: actually i would like to know more about updating the database version...is the database version referring to the version in the android manifest version (say, changes from 1 to 2)?

Comment: No. Changing the manifest version does not cause the `onUpgrade()` on your `SQLiteHelper` to be called. It will only be called if the versions of the database are different. The version of your database is specified on the `SQLiteHelper` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the application settings and any private application files (like SQLite databases) are kept when the user updates the application.  They are only removed when the app is explicitly uninstalled.